# Qt: No rule to make target 'release/projectname.o'. Stop

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set icon for my Qt application following this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html). When I run in release mode, this error appears:

> No rule to make target 'release/projectname.o'/ Stop.

Here is my `.pro` file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-01-05T12:03:20
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Muasaa
TEMPLATE = app

#CONFIG-=app_bundle

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    databasemanager.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    databasemanager.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

QT += sql

OTHER_FILES +=

RESOURCES +=

RC_FILE = myapp.rc
```

Now I see a different error:

> [release/qrc_myappicon.cpp] Error 1

What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like build-time error. Are you sure you *run* in release mode? Maybe you only added

```
RC_FILE = myapp.rc
```

to debug section? Show me your .pro file here.

Comment: Yes, I am running in release mode, check the question again, I will post the .pro file

Comment: What are you running in release mode?

Comment: You said you are running in release mode. WHAT are you running?

Comment: I do the following everytime I change something in the .pro file: 1- Clean All, 2 - Run qMake and 3 - Build All

Comment: I run my application from the "Run" play icon (making sure the Release mode on top of the play Icon is set ) on Qt creator after I do all the steps I mentioned above

Comment: am I missing something, I am not sure if I follow what you mean !

Comment: I meant this is not run-time error. This is build-time error. You can not run your app if it's not built. And it's obviously not built because of build-time error. So this is error of linking.

Comment: Well, from the QT-Creator, I can run my application in both debug mode and release mode. It is just when I try to run the application with the this line: `RC_FILE = myapp.rc` !!